# Как вернутся на предыдущий шаг в ConversationHandler? Не работает register_next_step_handler (python-telegram-bot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, бот, python-telegram-bot

Делаю телеграм бота на Python с фрейморком python-telegram-bot.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как задать боту следующий шаг после `context.bot.answer_callback_query`.

**Пробовала сделать так:**

• `context.bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, on_massage)`
Получаю ошибку: `AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'register_next_step_handler'`

• `return on_massage(update, context)` Бот зависает, никаких ошибок не выводит.

**Вот часть кода, где нужно это применить:**

```
def on_massage(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    if query.data == 'klass':
        user_data = context.user_data
        category = 'Вид массажа'
        massage = 'Классический'
        user_data[category] = massage

        query.edit_message_text("Выберите дату: ", reply_markup=telegramcalendar.create_calendar())
        return STATE_SELECT_DATE

def on_select_date(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    bot = context.bot

    selected, date = telegramcalendar.process_calendar_selection(bot, update)
    if not selected:
        return ConversationHandler.END

    user_data = context.user_data
    text_data = date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    user_data['Дата'] = text_data

    keyboard = [[
        InlineKeyboardButton("12:00", callback_data='12'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("14:30", callback_data='14'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("16:00", callback_data='16')
    ]]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    query.edit_message_text(text='''Вы выбрали %s
Выберите свободное время: ''' % text_data, reply_markup=reply_markup)
    return STATE_SELECT_TIME

def on_time_12(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    user_data = context.user_data
    text_time = '12:00'
    user_data['Время'] = text_time

    query = update.callback_query

    if check(user_data['Дата'], user_data['Время']):
        context.bot.answer_callback_query(update.callback_query.id, text='Извините, это время занято, выберите другое!', show_alert=True)
        print('Найдено в бд')
    else:
        query.answer()
        query.edit_message_text('''Введите своё *Имя и Фамилию*''', parse_mode='Markdown')
        return STATE_SELECT_USER
```

Помогите, пожалуйста. Буду очень благодарна за помощь!

Comment: Погуглил про `register_next_step_handler`, это ведь из библиотеки `telebot`?

Comment: Да, я знаю, что это из ```telebot```, но думала что в ```python-telegram-bot``` тоже применяется. Но ни с ```register_next_step```, ни каких либо-других примеров для возвращения бота на предыдущий шаг не нашла

Comment: На вопрос возвращения на предыдущий шаг я ответить не смогу. Задайте, пожалуйста, вопрос у автора библиотеки (не смог найти по вашей теме: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues?q=) или задайте вопрос на английском стеке. Только предоставьте минимальный пример. **PS.** знал бы, что у вас будут такие трудности предложил бы переписать `telegramcalendar` на `telebot`, кст, если вы попробуйте это делать и возникнут проблемы, сделайте вопрос, я бы попробовал вам с этим помочь :) (с telebot не работал, но, думаю, интересно будет)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Нашла решение своей проблемы**

```
def on_time_12(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    user_data = context.user_data

    text_time = '12:00'
    user_data['Время'] = text_time

    data_time = text_data + text_time

    query = update.callback_query

    if check(user_data['Дата'], user_data['Время']):
        context.bot.answer_callback_query(update.callback_query.id, text='Извините, это время занято, выберите другое!', show_alert=True)
        print('Найдено в бд')

        message = update.effective_message
        message.reply_text("Выберите дату: ", reply_markup=telegramcalendar.create_calendar())
        # ИЛИ
        # query.answer()
        # query.edit_message_text("Выберите дату: ", reply_markup=telegramcalendar.create_calendar())
        
        return STATE_SELECT_DATE
    else:
        query.answer()
        query.edit_message_text('''Введите своё *Имя и Фамилию*''', parse_mode='Markdown')
        return STATE_SELECT_TIME
```

И чтобы mysql не выдавал ошибок при повторной проверке, нужно добавить `buffered=True` в строку `mycursor = mydb.cursor()`

**ConversationHandler**

```
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', on_main_menu))

    dp.add_handler(ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[
            CommandHandler('start', on_main_menu),
        ],
        states={
            STATE_SELECT_MASSAGE: [
                CallbackQueryHandler(on_massage)
            ],

            STATE_SELECT_DATE: [
                CallbackQueryHandler(on_select_date)
            ],

            STATE_SELECT_TIME: [
                CallbackQueryHandler(on_time_12, pattern='12'),
                CallbackQueryHandler(on_time_14, pattern='14'),
                CallbackQueryHandler(on_time_16, pattern='16')
            ]
        },
        fallbacks=[

        ],
        # allow_reentry=True,
        # per_message=True,
    ))

    dp.add_error_handler(on_error)
```

Comment: Вы молодец, что разобрались, а как выглядит `ConversationHandler`?

Comment: @gil9red, добавила ConversationHandler, который отвечает за часть кода с вопроса. Или вас интересует весь?

Comment: `return STATE_SELECT_DATE` помог вернуться на шаг, что был до этого? Ведь сначала был `STATE_SELECT_DATE`, после `STATE_SELECT_TIME` и тут нам, при определенном условии, нужно вернуться к `STATE_SELECT_DATE`

Comment: Да, всё верно, `return STATE_SELECT_DATE ` помог корректно вернуться на шаг назад

Comment: Интересно... у меня это не получилось, возможно я что-то упустил

Comment: @gil9red, может вы `return STATE_SELECT_TIME` не спрятали в `else`? В таком случае у меня тоже не работал

Comment: Не, там даже проще. Взял пример из вашего вопроса https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/d2937cfc195292d32d1488ee7dc1257a232a5f0d/telegram_bot_examples/massage_ConversationHandler.py и для `on_time_14` принудительно после `query.answer()` добавил `return STATE_SELECT_DATE`, думаю, это должно было вернуть на предыдущий шаг, но не получилось